# similar list.append statements returning different results

Tags: python

I have the two expressions below, which to me are basically the same but the first line gives a list with generator inside rather than the values while the second one works fine.

I just wanted to know why this happens what is a generator and how its used.

```
newer_list.append([sum(i)] for i in new_list)

for i in new_list:
        newer_list.append([sum(i)])
```

Comment: The first only has one call to `append()` the second has one call for each member of `new_list`. (A generator is an object in its own right and can therefore be appended to a list).

Comment: In the first case, use `list.extend()` instead of `list.append()`

Comment: Oh yes, is there a reason that every call to `sum()` is wrapped in a list: `[sum(i)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generator is a way for Python to keep from storing everything in memory. The expression `([sum(i)] for i in new_list)` is a formula for generating the items in a list. To keep from storing that list in memory, it just stores the function it would need to execute, which has less of a memory footprint.

To turn a generator into a list, you can just do `list([sum(i)] for i in new_list)`, or in this case `([[sum(i)] for i in new_list])`

Answer (score 2):

The first one has a generator expression `(sum[i] for i in new_list)`, while the second one just loops, adding the sum.

It is possible you wanted something like `newer_list.extend([sum(i) for i in new_list])`, where extend concatenates lists instead of just appending, and the whole thing is wrapped in brackets so it's a list comprehension instead of a generator.

Comment: im trying to return a list of lists which the second for statements does. By expanding the brackets it makes 1 list inside a list with the values which isnt what i want

Comment: Then wrap the `sum(i)` in brackets, and keep the outer brackets.